# Raphaeljs: How to get the elements reference back using event.target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, raphael

Currently I have an small application for drawing shapes.

Here is an example including my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/auyaC/

I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getBBox'`

Below stripped code where the error comes from

When the user clicks on a shape, I catch the event.target

```
var onMouseDown = function(event) {
    setBBoxes($(event.target)); // Seems OK
};
```

I want the BBoxes back again but my shape has lost the BBox..

```
var setBBoxes = function(shape) {
    shape.getBBox(); // Unable.. getBBox is part of Raphael shapes, but mine is not the real reference?
};
```

And a stripped example: http://jsfiddle.net/auyaC/2/

## Edit

Ok so my problem was mixing up jQuery and Raphaeljs, because I am unable to use the mouse events of Raphael.

It seem that none of the examples online using mouse events or touch events work.

I have read these issue reports

- https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/720
- https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/pull/737

Also Windows thinks I have touch input available for 255 touch points.

But I don't have a touchscreen anymore (had one but changed screen and deleted drivers).

[image: Properties]

So for me, even http://jsfiddle.net/5BPXD doesn't work on my computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the fix for my bug...

It seem that Raphael thought that I had a touch screen.

The "Tablet PC Components" Windows feature was turned on. After disabling this feature, I was able to use the mouse and touch events again!

[image: Turn Windows features on or off. To turn a feature on, select its check box. To turn a feature off, clear its check box. A filled box means that only part of the feature is turned on. ... Tablet PC Components]

Answer (score 2):

You generally do not want to mix jQuery and Raphael like this, as it's easy to get confused about which library's event handlers and methods you're using. You also lose Raphael's fallback capabilities for old browsers when you start directly messing with the DOM elements that Raphael creates.

In this case, I recommend adding the `.mousedown()` listener directly to the Raphael element.

```
var paper = new Raphael($(".testarea")[0], $(".testarea").width(), $(".testarea").height());
var circAttr = {
    "fill": "#4ba6e8",
    "stroke": "#1a81cc",
    "stroke-width": "2"
};

paper.circle(200, 200, 80).attr(circAttr).mousedown(function() {
    someFunction(this);
});


var someFunction = function(shape) {
    console.log(shape.getBBox());    
};
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/auyaC/3/

Of course, you lose the ability to select all the shapes at once with a selector and add the event to all of them at once. You'll need to add the mousedown event to each one as it's created. Small tradeoff, I think.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but Raphael's mousedown, mousemove, mouseup, drag, the touch gestures (touchstart, touchmove, touchend etc.) are all broken! So these gesture events has to be triggered using jQuery... Using Google Chrome 27 and FireFox 22

Comment: Come again? Is this a documented bug?

Comment: Can't find this in the docs. But for me, even this won't work: http://jsfiddle.net/5BPXD/

Comment: @Bondye your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5BPXD/) works fine on my Chrome Version 27.0.1453.116. Even I recommend that you don't mix jQuery and Raphael events. The primary reason being the vastly different way in which the two libraries manage events.

Comment: Mmmm, than the issue is somewhere else.. BTW, my windows thinks he has touch input available for 255 touch points. Could that be the issue? I have read https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/720 & https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/pull/737